# Pass a value in stepper using React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, stepper

i have a problem in stepper where i want to pass the value From step 1 into step 2. In step 1, there shows a list of 'Senarai Barang' which the table has checkbox for doing selection. User must tick at least 1 rows before go to next step. In step 2, i want to display the list that has been selected in step 1. Here my codes:

```
export default function MohonQTB() {

  const [senaraiBarang, setSenaraiBarang] = useState<senaraiBarangItem[]>([]);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState<number[]>([]);


  interface senaraiBarangItem{
    id: "",
      no_kenalan: "",
      nama_barang: "",
      kuantiti: "",
      no_permohonan: "",
      no_kawalan: "",
  }
  
  const onSelect = (rows: any) => {
    console.log("Selected Rows:", rows)
  }

  const handleNextStep = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  
  const handleNext = () => {
    const newActiveStep =
      isLastStep() && !allStepsCompleted()
        ? steps.findIndex((step, i) => !(i in completed))
        : activeStep + 1;
    setActiveStep(newActiveStep);
  };

  const handleComplete = () => {
    const newCompleted = completed;
    newCompleted[activeStep] = true;
    setCompleted(newCompleted);
    handleNext();
  };

  /*-------------- Hantar -----------*/
  const kembali = () => {
    console.log(TAG + "DBG:Go To Next Page : Permohonan QTB");
    console.log(TAG + " DBG:Please Put Path to router.push()");
    router.push(`/perolehan-qtb/`);
  };

  /*-------------- Go Back -----------*/
  const hantar = () => {
    console.log(TAG + "DBG:Go To Next Page : Hantar Permohonan QTB");
    console.log(TAG + " DBG:Please Put Path to router.push()");
    router.push(`/perolehan-qtb/`);
  };


  const handleRowSelection = (rows: number[]) => {
    setSelectedRows(rows);
  };

  return (
    
                  <div>
                    {allStepsCompleted() ? (
                      <React.Fragment/>
                    ) : (
                      <React.Fragment>
                        {activeStep === 0 && (
                          <Box sx={{ padding: 2 }}>
                            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                              <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                  <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                                    <Box justifyContent="center" alignItems={"center"}>
                                      <Box>
                                        {senaraiBarang.length > 0 ? (
                                          <>
                                          <DataTable
                                            columns={columns}
                                            rows={senaraiBarang.map((item: any, index: any) => {
                                              return {
                                                ...(item as Record<string, unknown>),
                                                id: index + 1,
                                                userInput: (
                                                            <input type="checkbox"
                                                            checked={selectedRows.includes(item.id)}
                                                            onChange={() => handleRowSelection([...selectedRows, item.id])}
                                                            />
                                                ),
                                              };
                                            })}
                                            initialState={{
                                              pagination: {
                                                paginationModel: {page: 0, pageSize: 10},
                                              },
                                            }}
                                            customPageSize={10}
                                            sx={{
                                              width: "100%",
                                              padding: "0rem",
                                            }}
                                            // disableRowSelectionOnClick
                                            checkboxSelection
                                          />
                                          </>
                                        ) : (
                                          <Grid sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                                            <Typography
                                              variant="subtitle2"
                                              sx={{ color: "#242424", opacity: "0.5" }}
                                            >
                                              Tiada Maklumat
                                            </Typography>
                                          </Grid>
                                        )}
                                      </Box>
                                    </Box>
                                  </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                              </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                          </Box>
                        )}

                        {activeStep === 1 && (
                          <Box sx={{ padding: 2 }}>
                            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                              <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                                <Grid container spacing={2}>

                                  <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                      <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                                        <Box justifyContent="center" alignItems={"center"}>
                                          {/* <Box>
                                            {senaraiBarang.length > 0 ? (
                                              <DataTable
                                                columns={columns}
                                                rows={senaraiBarang
                                                  .map((item: any, index: any) => {
                                                    return {
                                                      ...(item as Record<string, unknown>),
                                                      id: index + 1,
                                                    };
                                                  })}
                                                initialState={{
                                                  pagination: {
                                                    paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 10},
                                                  },
                                                }}
                                                customPageSize={10}
                                                sx={{
                                                  width: "100%",
                                                  padding: "0rem",
                                                }}
                                              />
                                            ) : (
                                              <Grid sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                                                <Typography
                                                  variant="subtitle2"
                                                  sx={{ color: "#242424", opacity: "0.5" }}
                                                >
                                                  Tiada Maklumat
                                                </Typography>
                                              </Grid>
                                            )}
                                          </Box> */}
                                          <Box sx={{ padding: 2 }}>
                                            <DataTable
                                              columns={confirmBarangColumns}
                                              rows={senaraiBarang
                                                  .filter((item: any) => selectedRows.includes(item.id))
                                                .map((item: any, index: any) => {
                                                  return {
                                                    ...(item as Record<string, unknown>),
                                                    id: index + 1,
                                                  };
                                                })}
                                              initialState={{
                                                pagination: {
                                                  paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 10 },
                                                },
                                              }}
                                              customPageSize={10}
                                              sx={{
                                                width: "100%",
                                                padding: "0rem",
                                              }}
                                            />
                                          </Box>
                                        </Box>
                                      </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                  </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                              </Grid>
                              
                              
                              <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
                                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={1.5}>
                                    <CustomFormLabel
                                      htmlFor="nama_pelulus"
                                      sx={{ mt: 0, mb: {xs: "-10px", sm: 0} }}
                                    >
                                      {t("Mat.NamaPelulus", { ns: "mat" })}
                                    </CustomFormLabel>
                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
                                    <CustomTextField
                                      id="nama_qtb"
                                      name="nama_qtb"
                                      disabledValue="nama_qtb"
                                      fullWidth
                                    />
                                  </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                              </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                          </Box>
                        )}
                        <Box
                          sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", pt: 2 }}
                        >
                          {(() => {
                            if(activeStep != 0) {
                              return (
                                <Button
                                  color="primary"
                                  onClick={handleBack}
                                >
                                  {t("Mat.Kembali", { ns: "mat" })}
                                </Button>
                              );
                            } else {
                              return (
                                <Button onClick={kembali} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                                  {t("Mat.Kembali", { ns: "mat" })}
                                </Button>
                              );
                            }
                          })()}
                          <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto" }} />
                          {(() => {
                            if (activeStep != 1) {
                              return (
                                // <Button onClick={handleNextStep} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                                <Button onClick={() => setActiveStep(1)}>
                                  {t("Umum.Seterusnya")}
                                </Button>
                              );
                            } else {
                              return (
                                <Button
                                  color="success"
                                  sx={{ mr: 1 }}
                                  type="submit"
                                  onClick={hantar}
                                >
                                  {t("Mat.Hantar", { ns: "mat" })}
                                </Button>
                              );
                            }
                          })()}
                        </Box>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                  </div>
  );
}
```

The problem that i facing is, step 2 does not shows any data that has been selected in step 1. Help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Despite any error, React favors your app to be modularized into one or more components. That is, you should first decompose the above code in several small pieces (components) much easier to maintain, debug, and yet likely reusable.